# Atmega168 interrupts not working

Tags: atmega, interrupts

I am trying some simple programs to test my microcontroller, but I am having trouble with the first test program: blinking an LED using interrupts.

I'm using an **Atmega168A-PU**.

Here is my program:

```
#include <avr/io.h>

    #include <avr/delay.h>
    #include <avr/interrupt.h>

  //ISR(TIMER0_OVF) -> this syntax also not works
    ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
    {
        PORTB ^= (1 << PB1);
    }

    int main(void)
    {
        DDRB |= (1 << PB1); // set PB1 as output
        PORTB |= (1 << PB1); // led on
        TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0); // enable timer overflow interrupt
        TCCR0B |= (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02);  //set prescaler to 1024

        sei();
        while(1)
        {

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

All of the connections are good, but the LED won't blink.

Answer (score 1):

You are using 8-bit TC. It overflows at 255, which even with 1024 prescaler is too fast to see any blinking.

Also, check the generated code. I've seen reports of some older versions of compilers "optimizing" away infinite loops like that.

Comment: I can't agree with you. In my older version of atmega(16a), the same code worked good. Atmega168a has 8Mhz processor clock speed which can be divided by 8(CKDIV8). 1Mhz / 1024 =  ~ 976. 1 / 976 = 0,00102 which is 1.02 ms per each counter update.  Counter counts to 255, so each ovf interrupt occures every after 256ms. 256ms * 4 = 1024ms which is ~ 1 second. It gaves 4 state changes per second. I think it should can be seen by the human eye.

Comment: Does your LED stay ON all the time?

Comment: Yes. The same code adjusted to Atmega16 works good.

Comment: Try replacing |= with = for TIMSK0 and TCCR0B and set TCCR0A = 0

Comment: I changed, but nothing happen. I can make led blinking but using delay_ms(...) in main loop but it doesn't satisfy me.

Comment: Well, can you use delay for 256 ms and see if the blinking is noticeable?

Comment: Yest, but I think something is not good with clock rate. When my clock rate is set to 8Mhz, _delay_ms(1000) takes about 3seconds! With CKDIV8 set it takes about 20 seconds! Why is that? What's wrong?

Comment: Have you set F_CPU properly? delay does not use RTC, it simply loops, so it depends on system clock

Comment: Yes I'm sure that it set properly. I have no idea why is that. I change chip to another(the same model), and nothing change.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you changing F_CPU when you changing CKDIV8? Because not changing it is the only explanation why delay could be different. Also, try TIM0_OVF_vect just in case, Atmel engineers seem to be incapable of consistency. And finally, are you using some kind of bootloader that you didn't use with Atmega16? Could be your IVSEL is wrong.

Comment: I think that the compiler is responsible of this problem. When I changed enviroment from CodeBlocks with their version of compiler to Eclipse with probably newest version of compiler, everything seems to be okay. The same code, compiled by different versions of compiler works different. After work I'll take a look into assembly code , generated by compiler because I'm curious where are differences.

Comment: Compiler cannot take care of F_CPU because it has no idea at what speed you will be running.